# AJV - Validation of complex schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, jsonschema, ajv

I am using [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) as my schema validator for API  inputs.

I need to validate if I received data in this format:

```
floors: [
    {
        name: "Floor 1",
        rooms: [
            {
                name: "Room 1"
            },
            ... more rooms
        ]
    },
    ... more floors
]
```

Basically it is `Array of Objects` and those Objects also have `Array of Objects`. Each floor has one or more rooms.

Is it possible to validate this data with a clean JSON Schema using AJV or do I need to write some custom keyword/validator for AJV?

I tried to do it but I ended up with this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
floors: {
    type: "object",
    minProperties: 1,
    properties: {
        name: {
            type: "string"
        },
        rooms: {
            type: "object",
            minProperties: 1,
            properties: {
                name: {
                    type: "string"
                }
            },
            required: ["name"]
        }
    },
    required: ["name", "rooms"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found solution myself:

```
floors: {
    type: "array",
    minItems: 1,
    items: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                name: {
                    type: "string"
                },
                rooms: {
                    type: "array",
                    minItems: 1,
                    items: {
                            type: "object",
                            properties: {
                                name: {
                                    type: "string"
                                }
                            },
                            required: ["name"],
                            additionalProperties: false,
                        },
                }
            },
            required: ["name", "rooms"],
            additionalProperties: false,
        }
}
```

Correct me if it have there some security holes where you can leak some invalid stuff :)

Comment: If all objects in `floors.items` share the same structure, then you don't need to define `floors.items` as an array of schemas. It could just be assigned that schema directly.

Comment: Like that `floors.items = { ... }` instead of `floors.items = [ { ... } ]`

Comment: Yup! If `items` is a schema, then it applies to ALL items in the array as opposed to being applies to items at the same position only. Having `items` be an array with a single schem, means you're only validating the first item in the array. I don't think you want that.

Comment: minItems: 1 to validate array of objects